Jacoco not generating HTML report
I'm using jacoco for code coverage.  My problem is, I am getting a xml generated report, however I am not getting any html report, nor am I getting the jacoco-session.html
Here is my config:

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    configure<JacocoTaskExtension> {
        isIncludeNoLocationClasses = true
        excludes = mutableListOf("jdk.internal.*")
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.forEach { variant ->
        val variantName = variant.name.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.ENGLISH) else it.toString() }
        val testTaskName = "test${variantName}UnitTest"

        val reportTask = tasks.create("jacoco${testTaskName}Report", JacocoReport::class.java) {
            dependsOn(testTaskName)
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the $variantName build."

            reports {
                xml.required.set(true)
                html.required.set(true)
            }

            classDirectories.setFrom(
                files(
                    fileTree(variant.javaCompileProvider.get().destinationDir) {
                        exclude(fileFilter)
                    },
                    fileTree("${project.layout.buildDirectory}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${variantName}") {
                        exclude(fileFilter)
                    }
                )
            )

            sourceDirectories.setFrom( variant.sourceSets.flatMap { it.javaDirectories })
            executionData.setFrom(file("${project.layout.buildDirectory}/jacoco/$testTaskName.exec"))
        }

        tasks.findByName("jacocoTestReport")!!.dependsOn(reportTask)
    }
}

tasks.register("jacocoTestReport")

This all looks to be correct (to me) but I'm obviously going wrong somewhere on this.  If anyone could shed some light or provide some help I would be eternally grateful.
